# Is it possible to use a jQuery pagination script and print the results in a separate window?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery pagination script that I've downloaded and want to use it on a page where the user can page through the data and then, using a print button on that page, print the specific page they want.

The print button currently opens a pop-up window with a printer friendly layout. I need to somehow pass the paginated data over to this new window. I can do this with a PHP script by passing a GET variable with the page number to the new window but I'm pretty clueless with how to do this with JavaScript or if it's even possible at all.

Can someone tell me if what I'm wanting here can be done? If it can, I'd be happy to post some code.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but this seems to be a custom feature that needs to be thought out and implemented. I don't know of any plug-ins that do that out of the box!

Comment: @jnkrois, OK, that's what I thought... Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused...can't you just have the link open a new window with the proper query string? `<a href="somepage.php?page=5" target="_blank">Print This Page</a>`

Comment: @Bryan, I could do just that and is the easiest for me to do with PHP but I don't know how to get that query string into the print button using JQ. If I could figure that out, I'd be golden. Would you know how to achieve this

Comment: I totally missed the fact that you're using javascript for pagination. What pagination script are you using and have you customized it at all?

Comment: @ Bryan, I'm using an out of the box copy of "paginateTable". I have to say, it works very well and it's small. If I have to do this with PHP, it will obviously be more involved. If I can overcome this small issue of passing the link, it would save me countless lines in PHP. Would you have a look and give me your opinion on what it would take, please?

Comment: Can I see a link to your page? There are two different styles of pagination you can use with that script. The location of your print button in the DOM will probably matter as well as there doesn't appear to be a property you can reference to get the current page.

Comment: @Bryan, I don't have the site on a server yet and it's on my local machine so I can't provide a link unfortunately. I haven't integrated this script yet in any way so I'm open to any style of pagination that will work in my case. Whatever you think my best option is, is good enough for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function(){

    // http://www.bennadel.com/blog/695-Ask-Ben-Getting-Query-String-Values-In-JavaScript.htm
    var objURL = new Object(),
        printButton = ".print",
        key = "page_id",
        value = "";

    window.location.search.replace(
        new RegExp( "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g" ),
        function( $0, $1, $2, $3 ){
            objURL[ $1 ] = $3;
        }
    );
    value = objURL[key];

    $(printButton).click(function(){
        var url = "http://google.com?" + key + "=" + value;
        window.open(url, "_blank");
        return false;
    });

});
```

This creates an object `objURL` which contains the name-value pairs of the query string. Then you just attach a click handler to a print button that fires `window.open()` with the proper query string.

Comment: Bryan, I have it opening a new window now but the issue I'm having is that page number from the pagination isn't being passed into the query string. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the URL look like? Is it using `page_id=x`?